# I want to calculate cross entropy at all outputs of LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am writing a program of classification problem using LSTM.
However, I do not know how to calculate cross entropy with all the output of LSTM.
Here is a part of my program.

```python
cell_fw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_hidden)
cell_bw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_hidden)
outputs, _ = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw,cell_bw,inputs = inputs3, dtype=tf.float32,sequence_length= seq_len)

outputs = tf.concat(outputs,axis=2)

#outputs [batch_size,max_timestep,num_features]
outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, num_hidden*2])

W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden*2,
                                     num_classes],
                                    stddev=0.1))

b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0., shape=[num_classes]))

logits = tf.matmul(outputs, W) + b
```

How can I apply crossentropy error to this?
Should I create a vector that represents the same class as the number of max_timestep for each batch and calculate the error with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at `cross_entropy` documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/softmax_cross_entropy ?

The dimension of `onehot_labels` should answer your question.